# What is the length of a singleton set?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider a set $\{0\}$, what is its length? It cannot be zero because having infinitely many singletons, we could construct a set $[0,1]$ which is of length one. However assigning an arbitrarily small number to its length would result in a set $[0,1]$ having an infinite length.

Comment: $\mu(\cup_{i\in I} A_i)=\sum_{i\in I} \mu (A_i)$ holds if I is countable

Comment: Lebesgue measure is countably additive. What you have realized here is that it cannot be $|\mathbb R|$-additive. That is, though the union of countably many singletons has measure $0$, the union of ``$|\mathbb R|$-many'' singletons does not need to have measure $0$. Sometimes it does. Sometimes it doesn't: There are sets of positive measure. Sometimes, it does not even have a measure: There are non-measurable sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Length" is generally a concept that is only going to be *countably* additive. And since $[0, 1]$ is uncountable, it's not a countable union of singletons, and assigning length $0$ to a singleton leads to no contradictions.

Comment: What if $[0,1]$ was a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$?, then it would be countable - a countable union of singletons. But even here we cannot assign the length $0$ to a singleton.

Comment: @DavidToth Why not? In the usual definition of length, the only sensible definition for $\ell(\Bbb Q)$ is zero.

Comment: @TBongers  measure theory differs from set theory in set theory you have cardinal numbers the cardinal number is the number of elements , {0} has one element so its cardinal number is 1. [0,1] as infinite numbers  (aleph 0 or Aleph 1, depending if you allow irrational numbers or not)

Comment: @Willemien Yes, but I don't see your point. Length is a concept that's fundamental to measure theory, not set theory.

Comment: @T.Bongers I did not know that $l(\mathbb{Q})=0$, thank you for the introduction.

Comment: @T.Bongers you are richt in this , but  the questions mentions sets, it  previously had the set Theory tag, and the closest to length  in set theory ia a cardinal number (okay it ia all a bit far fetched)